# Como alterar um atributo numa lista de objetos e escrever essa lista num arquivo

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, arquivo, lista, objetos

Eu tenho uma lista de objetos`conList` que eu quero alterar um atributo de um objeto e depois escrever essa lista em um arquivo, onde cada linha do arquivo é um atributo de cada objeto na lista.
Como eu faço isso ?

Edit:

Código que eu tenho até agora:

```
 def carregarConsumiveis(self):
    consList=[]
    arq=open('Consumiveis.dat', 'r')
    i=0
    tipo=''
    nome=''
    codigo=''
    quantidade=''
    preco=''
    for linha in arq:
        if i==0:
            tipo=linha
        elif i==1:
            nome=linha
        elif i==2:
            codigo=linha
        elif i==3:
            quantidade=linha
        elif i==4:
            preco=linha
            consumivelarq=Consumivel(tipo,nome,codigo,quantidade,preco)
            consList.append(consumivelarq)
            i = -1
        i+=1
    arq.close()
    return consList
```

Eu quero alterar um atributo de um objeto com um certo nome, e reescrever no arquivo.

Comment: Tem como colocar na pergunta o código que possui hoje? Se cada linha no arquivo será um atributo e você possui uma lista de objetos, como saberá quando termina um e inicia outro no arquivo?

Comment: e tambem um exemplo do formato do arquivo final, e, principalmente, o código que você já tentou fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi o problema, obrigado a todos que ajudaram.
Aqui tá a solução que eu achei pra esse problema.

```
def adicionarQuantidade(self,consumivel):

    consList = self.carregarConsumiveis()
    for con in consList:
        if con.nome == (consumivel.nome+'\n'):
            newqntd=(int(con.quantidade))+(int(consumivel.quantidade))
            con.quantidade=newqntd
            self.reescrevendo(consList)

def reescrevendo(self, consList):

    arq = open('Consumiveis.dat', 'w')
    for i in consList:
        arq.write(str(i.tipo))
        arq.write(str(i.nome))
        arq.write(str(i.codigo))
        arq.write(str(i.quantidade)+'\n')
        arq.write(str(i.preco))
    arq.close()
```

A função `adicionarQuantidade` tá verificando se algum objeto do arquivo tem o mesmo nome do objeto que eu quero salvar, se tiver ele edita o atributo quantidade, somando o antigo com o novo e por fim chama a função `reescrevendo` que reescreve a lista no arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar sua solução. Não se esqueça de marcar sua resposta como solução para sua pergunta.